# Create Custom Buttons in Google Apps Script for Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to find a way to create my own custom text for a ButtonSet in Google Apps Script. I do not want to use one of the default options of YES, NO, OK, etc. I would like the buttons to read: 'Today' and 'Tomorrow'. This is what I have tried so far, but I am having no luck...any thoughts on how I could accomplish this? Thank you!

```
// Create custom button text for Today and Tomorrow
  var TodayButton = CardService.newTextButton()
  .setText("Today");
  var TomorrowButton = CardService.newTextButton()
  .setText("Tomorrow");
  var DayButtonSet = CardService.newButtonSet()
  .addButton(TodayButton)
  .addButton(TomorrowButton);

  var responseWeatherImpactsDate = ui.alert('Do you want the first day of the Weather Impacts table to be today or tomorrow?', DayButtonSet);
```

Comment: Do you get your ui alert? What do the buttons say?

Comment: The ui alert does not pop up. I get an error that says "Cannot find method alert(string, ButtonSet).

Comment: what about ui.prompt?

Comment: I don't need the user to enter any information, so have no use for ui.prompt as far as I know. Just need the user to select a button, either 'Today' or 'Tomorrow'. Then I will use their response to proceed to the next step.

Comment: @hunter21188 Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, for example, how about using the custom dialog? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs

Comment: You are getting the "cannot find method alert" error because the [syntax](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alert(String,ButtonSet)) is wrong. alert() works with (String, ButtonSet), and ButtonSet only works with [predetermined values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set). As @Tanaike said, you should consider using custom dialogs. 
Also, clarifying what you are trying to do with the buttons would be helpful to find a solution.

Comment: The custom dialog option might work if I can add two custom buttons, but I still see no way of doing that. If the user selects 'Today' it will auto populate a table with a list of dates starting today. If they select 'tomorrow', it will populate those dates starting with tomorrow.

Comment: Here is a link to a Google Doc (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o064KjTJsYz576odTTkq_MM3fsl1yk93VCsMBD3Zbgc/edit?usp=sharing) with the necessary info. There is only one script associated with it and the code I have is there. Hope this helps. @Jescanellas

Comment: Thanks for sharing the document. I just realised we all supposed this was for Sheets API. As far as I know you can't create a user interface in Docs, the Ui method is a Spreadsheet function and since you want to make an interactive table, I encourage you to do this in Sheets.